# Are jumper wires just wires with insulation cut off on both ends?

Tags: wire

Is there a specific purpose for jumper wires like [these](http://spacetinkerer.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-make-your-own-breadboard-jumper.html) where they have female pins at the ends?  I'm assuming they are mainly useful when you want to chop a wire into something like a breadboard, but the wire is too thin or flimsy.  If the wire is thick enough, I'm assuming a wire with the insulation cut off on both sides is equivalent, right?  Seems like a common sense question, but I haven't really seen wires with female pins attached on both sides before.. :)

Comment: F-F, M-F, and M-M jumpers do exist: http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/65

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are connecting to actual female pins, it does help to have the right sized male pin crimped onto your jumper wires. But if you're just using them on a breadboard, bare wire ends are fine. Just make sure to cut the wire with diagonal cutters, not scissor-type cutters, so that you get a nice pointy end. The shearing action of scissor type cutters can sometimes roll the wire end enough to make it snag in the breadboard.

Answer (score 5):

Only potential reasons for *maybe* soldering male header pins on the end would be if using stranded core wires or a really small gauge solid core (like 24 or 26 gauge).

A lot of in-wall cat5/cat6 cable is going to be 24 gauge solid core which *should* work as-is in most breadboards. 22 or 20 would give a firmer/more-confident connection though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're wondering if having female ended wires available is useful?BTW The ones in the link look like double male ended wires. (which yea generically you could get by with a wire). As far as female I think a useful aspect would be if you have two sets of components with headers connected, then you can just connect the "male headers" to male headers and you're golden.